# Angular HostBinding property from Base Component

Tags: angular

Can someone explain me how is my HostBinding in nested component understand that we already have "isTablet" property and just add "is-tablet" class to my host element ?

Webstorm says that we have overrided base isTablet property but my child component has TRUE in this property.

I can't find any explanations in official documentation

```
  export abstract class DetailBase {
       @Input() isTablet: boolean = true;
  }

  export class ChildComponent extends DetailBase {
       @HostBinding('class.is-tablet') isTablet: boolean; //why it is TRUE ?
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Typescript-specific behaviour. If member of the class has not defined value at all, transpiled javascript doesn't include this member at all. Take a look at transpiled javascript [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20DetailBase%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isTablet%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) and [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20DetailBase%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isTablet%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A):

Because extended class has defined value for member `isTablet`, child class has access to `isTablet` through prototypal inheritance.